# Is this REST protocol?

Tags: android, json, apache, http, rest

I used this code in my Android application:

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
...
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://myServerAddress");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(myArrayList));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Is correct to say that this code uses REST protocol?

--- edit ---

(server-side I used a script that returns a JSON object)

Comment: That code is just a HTTP POST request, there's nothing there to indicate whether it's REST or otherwise. Why are you asking?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) says "REST is an architecture, unlike SOAP, which is a protocol" - so "uses REST protocol" is kind of incorrect

Comment: @zapl REST is an architectural style, which makes it even more abstract than an architecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

REST is a server-side architecture. It is not possible to determine from this client code whether the server has such an API architecture. "Maybe."

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking REST is neither a protocol nor an architecture, but an architectural 'style' ( a certain way to create an architecture or part of an architecture).. It is quite common for an architecture that confirms to teh REST style to be refered to a RESTful

Pragmatically speaking REST uses the HTTP protocol, to create, read, update and delete (CRUD) resources that are addressable by a URL, using HTTP POST (create), HTTP GET (read), HTTP PUT (update) and HTTP DELETE (delete).

More theoretically, REST means Representational State Transfer, in which "Representational" refers to the representation of a resource (the content of a get or post request or response) that is sent or received in a (HTTP) request, and  the fact that by doing a request you are "transfering" the "State" of a resource from client to server or vice-versa.

Beyond the main criteria of a resource being addressable uniquely by a URL and the use of the HTTP verbs (POST, PUT...etc) for CRUD, there are some more aspects of REST, such a that transitions of states should ideally only occur by links provided in the resource, resource should be linked based on link relations types, and alike... but that can get a bit religious quite quickly :-)

I would be tempted to call an Archticture RESTful if it has resources properly uniquely addressable by URLS and if it uses POST, GET, PUT and DELETE for CRUD...

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Your piece of code shows you use HTTP protocol not that you use REST. REST is a Design approche not a Protocol.

That means you make a POST to a REST Server. Because it's a POST the values you post should be in the Request Body. So first question : Witch format your REST server uses to exchange data ? JSON, XML ? Some other formats?

I assume it's JSON. Second question : Your httpclient is it able to send JSON content ?

A classic example of a REST POST is
POST on "http://myServerAddress/car" with JSON in the request body {"brand":"ford","model":"mustang"}

You can use a firefox plugin like RESTClient for firefox to try manually to do your POST request on your server. It will be easier after to finish your android code.

Answer (score -1):

Using REST to implement a web services API means that you access them via URL, as if "you were fetching a web page". This means that is very easy to interact with this kind of WS, because you do not have to deal with the complexity of SOAP, in which you must declare the WSDL and so one in the server side...

In conclusion, you have some code that actually does some POST to some URL. It will depend on what actually this URL access does. It is a very common approach to return XML or JSON from a WS, so it that cases you could be almost sure that you are accessing a restful WS.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot!! This code communicates with a PHP script...
and the script returns a JSON object.
therefore i use the rest Protocol

Comment: Even though that's a common way to describe REST, that's rather CRUD over HTTP. Being RESTful includes using Hypermedia types that drive the interaction via hyper-links (a.k.a HATEOAS = "Hypermedia as the Engine of Application State")

Comment: That's right, accessing a URL is not what REST is. So I don't think this answer is correct.

Comment: mmm.. I'm officially confused..  
Wikipedia says: Conforming to the REST constraints is generally referred to as being "RESTful"... so my code is restful?

Comment: The same way as a single molecule cannot be hot or cold, being restful or not is not a quality of code, it's a quality of architecture.

Comment: in CRUD POST=Create.. but in my case POST=read => not RESTful... thanks and sorry if I was insistent

Comment: @SeanOwen Of course, accessing an URL is not what REST is, I hope we all know this! But as LucaZap says, he is accessing a script via HTTP through an URL that identifies that resource, which in turn returns a JSON response. So... why do you think my response is incorrect? By RESTful we are referring to code that envolves REST ws. By the way, thanks for the downvote, glad to help!

Comment: REST means more than this. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer For example, nothing about this tells you that the server identifies resources in the REST style. This is why I believe your answer is wrong, and have given good evidence, and so voted it down. This is how StackOverflow works. Don't get offended; I get downvoted all the time. I fix, delete or defend my answers.

Comment: @SeanOwen I had already read that, as I worked a little with it some time ago. And do not worry! ;)